# Cursor observe did not fire the added property

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client side suppose to fire the `console.log('added')` but did not even though the server added a document which matches the query as well as the browser console `myCollection.find().fetch()` shows the document is present. Any ideas why and how to fix it? Thanks

```
myCollection.find({prop1: val1, prop2: val2}).observe({
      added: function (newDoc) {
        console.log('added');
      }
});
```

```js
// client
Template.body.onCreated(function () {
  this.autorun(function () {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      Meteor.subscribe('myCollection', Session.get('prop1')); //6e
    }
  });
});

// server
Meteor.publish('myCollection', function (val1) {
      return DataTeckCol.find({prob1: value1}, { 
});
```

Comment: It's not enough information to understand your issue. What is `myCol`? Is it client or server code? Where are your publications/subscriptions?

Comment: make sure val1 and val2 are what you think they are

Comment: Your publication code has 2 issues: 1) using `prob1` instead of `prop1`; 2) using `value1` instead of `val1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try below code,

```
myCollection.find({prop1: val1, prop2: val2}).observeChanges({
      added: function (id, fields) {
        console.log('added');
      }
});
```

also please specify where have you written above code?